# Angular2 Subscribe to a global variable

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm fairly new to Angular 2 and I have a little problem.
I have a header component, in the header I want to use an `ngIf`, cause in the login-screen I will hide the header(navbar).
Furthermore, I want to hide some more things from the header, depending on the users-profile.

To store, if a user is logged in, I have a global service named **variables.ts**, which looks like this:

```
    import { Injectable }   from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Variables {
    private url = "...";
    private username;
    private password;
    private isLoggedIn = false;

    constructor() {}

    setUrl(val) {
        this.url = val;
    }
    getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }

    setUsername(val) {
        this.username = val;
    }
    getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    setPassword(val) {
        this.password = val;
    }
    getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    setIsLoggedIn(val) {
        this.isLoggedIn = val;
    }
    getIsLoggedIn() {
        return this.isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

My header-component looks like this:

```
    import { Component }            from '@angular/core';
import { Router }               from '@angular/router';
import { Variables }            from '../../services/variables';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'header.component.html'
})


export class HeaderComponent {

    constructor(private variables: Variables) {}
    isLoggedIn() {  
        return this.variables.getIsLoggedIn();
    }
    console.log(loggedIn); 
}
```

And last but not least, in the header.component.html I did this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" *ngIf="isLoggedIn()">
```

My problem now is, that the header-component do not automatically update the var `loggedIn`, so the header is hidden if I'm logged in.

How can i make it functional?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572005/persisting-and-accessing-values-globally-in-multiple-components-in-angular-2

Comment: thanks for the comment, but if i implement this, i get an "No Directive annotation found on Variables"...
Do you know any help?

Comment: Post code how you implemented your global service.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: I think it's better to move these variables to a service that you provide in `@NgModule({providers: [myService]}) class AppModule{}` and use an `Observable` (or `Subject`, `BehaviorSubject`) to allow interested components to subscribe to changes. See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 0):

I updated my original post, so that it is functional now ;)
Thanks for your help!

Solution: Don´t bind it directly to a variable, but to a function and in the "ngIf" just ask the function ;)

Comment: `return this.variables.getIsLoggedIn();` creates an unconnected copy and therefore changes to the original are not reflected. With your approach you don't create a copy but bind to the original and therefore Angular2 change detection detects the changes and updates the view.

Comment: There is a difference in how values are passed. Primitives like string, num, boolean are passed as copy, objects are passed as reference. When a reference is passed and the receiver modifies properties, then these changes are also visible in the original (they have a reference to the same object instance), this is not the case with primitives, because there are no references, only the values itself.