# Angular equivalent of AngularJS' ng-init with Default Values within Scope

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm transitioning from NGJS to NG and trying to recode my previous application to practice.

I stumbled upon the new NgInit where initializations are done in Angular's Component.

What I'm trying to achieve is to initialize a value WITHIN the scope to be used as a toggle to hide and unhide HTML elements.
I'm trying to solve this without looping within `ngOnInit() {}` to initialize for each object within the array. *(**See `ng-init` in `ng-repeat` block**)*

Below is a working copy of the scenario I'm trying to achieve:

```js
angular.module("app", [])

.controller("controller", function($scope) {
  
  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.modules = [
      {
        label: 'Module A',
        children: [
          'Module A - 1',
          'Module A - 2',
          'Module A - 3'
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'Module B',
        children: [
          'Module B - 1',
          'Module B - 2',
          'Module B - 3'
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'Module C',
        children: [
          'Module C - 1',
          'Module C - 2',
          'Module C - 3'
        ]
      }
    ];
  };
  
});
```

```css
.child {
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

.parent {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller" ng-init="init()">
  <div class="parent" ng-repeat="module in modules" ng-init="toggle=true">
    {{module.label}}
    <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">toggle</button>
    <span ng-if="toggle" id="child-group">
      <div class="child" ng-repeat="child in module.children">
        {{child}}
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's a Plunker if you prefer:
https://plnkr.co/edit/JDBBPLkr21wxSe2dlRBv?p=preview

Comment: You can "initialize" a variable, when you defined it, in constructor, or in ngOnInit function (your component must be implements OnInit). Generally is recomended make in ngOnInit

Comment: Yeah. But unfortunately, `NgOnInit` behaves differently from the previous `ng-init`. The initialized `toggle` is accessible only within the scope of initialization. Another thing is if I initialized the toggle in constructor, I have to define 1 boolean for each Parent which you don't want to do specially if you don't have any idea how many "modules" (in this case) the API gateway will respond.

Comment: In Angular js (as I remember it) $scope is "only". In Angular, if you want to mantein the value of a "variable" along the app life, you must use a "service" to save the variable, see, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572005/persisting-and-accessing-values-globally-in-multiple-components-in-angular-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this. 
You loop over your array with *ngFor. The button toggles the corresponding boolean value, which defines if your element is shown or not (with the *ngIf directive)

```
@Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     template: `
         <div *ngFor="let module of modules; let i = index">
         <button (click)="show[i] = !show[i]">toggle</button>
         <h2>{{module.label}}</h2>
         <div *ngIf="show[i]">
            <li *ngFor="let child of module.children">
             {{child}}
          </li>
         </div>
         </div>             
    `,
})
```

Then initialize your variables:

```
export class AppComponent {     
  modules:any[];
  show:boolean[];

  constructor() {
    this.modules = [
    {
       label: 'Module A',
       children: [
      'Module A - 1',
      'Module A - 2',
      'Module A - 3'
    ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Module B',
      children: [
      'Module B - 1',
      'Module B - 2',
      'Module B - 3'
    ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Module C',
      children: [
      'Module C - 1',
      'Module C - 2',
      'Module C - 3'
    ]
    }
    ];
      this.show = this.modules.map(()=>true);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hey Opp! Thanks! Had my navigation work as expected with this solution

Answer (score 2):

Implement `OnInit` while declaring the component's class and move your initialization code to `ngOnInit` function.

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class componentClass implements OnInit {
  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    // initialization code block
  }
}
```

Mention that Angular(Version2+) provides [life hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) for a component from been created to been destroyed.

---

For `ng-init` at `ng-repeat` part, From Angular2, you should use `ngFor` instead and `ngFor` only allows a limited set of local variables to be defined, see **[DOC](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)**.

Comment: Unfortunately, it behaved differently from `ng-init` in which I can initialize the values within the scope of directive. What if the array comes from an API and you don't have any idea how many objects the API will respond. I'm trying to solve the problem without looping through the array just to initialize the toggle boolean.

Comment: @MichaelArdan you meant to ask about `ng-init` at `ng-repeat` block?

Comment: Sorry if the question confused you. Yeah, I'm talking about the `ng-init` in my `ng-repeat` block. Edited the question

Comment: @MichaelArdan `ngFor` only allows a limited set of local variables to be defined. see https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

Comment: It seems that the same solution is not achievable in NG++. Thanks Pengyy

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your request, could you explain yourself better?
why do not you try to use the @component ...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tag-selector',
  templateUrl: './pagina.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pagina.css']
})
export class Controller{
  your code
}
```

Edit:

if you declare the $scope out of Init, it should work anyway

```
angular.module("app", [])

.controller("controller", function($scope) {

  $scope.init = function() {

  };
  $scope.modules = [{
    label: 'Module A',
    children: [
      'Module A - 1',
      'Module A - 2',
      'Module A - 3'
    ]
  }, {
    label: 'Module B',
    children: [
      'Module B - 1',
      'Module B - 2',
      'Module B - 3'
    ]
  }, {
    label: 'Module C',
    children: [
      'Module C - 1',
      'Module C - 2',
      'Module C - 3'
    ]
  }];

});
```

I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I fully understood the question ...

Comment: Hi Marco! The question was confusing sorry. I had to edit the question to clarify things. I was talking about `ng-init` beside my `ng-repeat`. In my sample, I have 3 `toggle` variables initialized. Changing the value of one of the `toggle` wouldn't affect the other 2 since it is declared only within the scope of the `ng-repeat`.